# What is the equivalent of the Java student[] * student array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C.  I have a Java array defined by

```
student[] * student
```

What is the equivalent for this in Objective-C?

Comment: what is this student[] *  can you explain this.

Comment: Maybe you want an NSArray or NSMutableArray

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C it is very common to use the **NSArray** class for this type of data storage.

You can **create** an NSArray as follows:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object0, object1, object2, nil];
```

Notice how the argument list is nil-terminated?

You can **access** objects in an NSArray as follows:

```
ClassName *myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:knownIndex];
// do something to myObject
```

There is much, much more you can do with NSArray's, so please read the documentation available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html). And **please** read the **memory-management** documentation available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

*Note:* NSArray is an immutable data structure, which means you cannot modify the list of objects it contains after it has been created. If you want an array whose list of objects you can modify, use **NSMutableArray**, documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks paulfi.I am a very new in c based on programming.

Comment: Could I ask you can give me a simple example with Student objects.

Comment: There are a lot of examples here: [Arrays: Ordered Collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF)

Comment: sorry I could not understand above informations that i had a look at. for example A.h                                                                    @interface Grade : NSObject  Student[] * student ;

Comment: what do I have to write into arrayWithObjects:object0, object1, object2, nil because I don't no how many objects will be. all so what is this objectAtIndex:knownIndex means.

Comment: @Grace - With all due respect, perhaps you should start at the beginning and review Apple's [Introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), then re-read the link that paulfi has provided.  You need to understand the fundamentals before any of this will make sense.